# Is there a way of writing '_tkinter.tkapp objects' to a file by using pickle, json or the like? - python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, serialization

I am trying to write tkinter 'widgets' to a file so that i can use them again in a different tkinter project. I have tried to use pickle and json to accomplish this but unfortunately it has been to no avail.
Here are the things that i have tried:

pickle:

```
def save(widgets):
    with open("testfile.pickle","wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(widgets,file) #TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects
```

json:

```
def save(widgets):
    with open("testfile.pickle","wb") as file:
        jsonWidgets = json.dumps(widgets) #TypeError: Object of type Button is not JSON serializable
        file.write(jsonWidgets)
```

if i use the print() function on the widgets variable I get this:

```
[{'widget': <tkinter.Button object .0>, 'type': 'button', 'font': <tkinter.font.Font object at 0x000001A4EC0AC860>, 'ID': 0, 'name': 'widget_no_0'}]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way of writing '_tkinter.tkapp objects' to a file by using pickle, json or the like? - python tkinter

No, there is no way to use pickle. Tkinter is a wrapper around an embeded tcl interpreter. The widgets are tcl objects not python objects, and python has no way to stream them to disk.

You can use JSON or any other storage mechanism you like to get the data out of the widgets and save the data to disk. At startup you will then need to read the data and insert it into the widgets.

Comment: so i am pretty much stuck?